# $ \mathbb{E}\left[\big(\mathbb{E}[X|Y]\big)^2\right] \leq \mathbb{E}(X^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I'm working on old qualifying exam problems and haven't been able to get this one yet.

> Let $X,Y$ be random variables with joint density function $f_{XY}$, $\mathbb{E}(X^2)<\infty$, and $\mathbb{E}(Y^2)<\infty$.
>
> Show that $ \mathbb{E}\left[\big(\mathbb{E}[X|Y]\big)^2\right] \leq \mathbb{E}(X^2). $

I assume using Jensen's inequality and the law of total expectation will help. I tried using those and also just applying the definition of conditional expectation, but I haven't gotten it.

Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This result with proof is given on the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality#General_inequality_in_a_probabilistic_setting Take the convex function to be $\varphi(x)=x^2$, and then take expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to @Byron's excellent suggestion, expand the inequality
$$
E[(X-E[X\mid Y])^2]\geqslant0,
$$
using the fact that
$$
E[XE[X\mid Y]]=E[E[X\mid Y]^2].
$$